# How to call and place customer dropdown attribute in Customer Registration Page and One Step Checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, customer-attribute, onestepcheckout, dropdown-attribute

I have made a custom customer dropdown attribute like shown in the screenshot (through Silk Software). See Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I was wondering how to make show the dropdown in the customer registration form template, so that new customers can choose any option and save it to their account information.

Is there also a way to show the dropdown in the checkout template for not registered users?

In the case of registered users, is there also a way to show the dropdown in the checkout template, so that the selected value shows or the options show for those who have not chosen? Would it be automatically saved in the database?